# Texture not shown in 3D Viewport

Tags: texturing

I know this question has been asked multiple times, however none of the answer I found applied to my case.
Please refer to my screenshot below, where I have the sphere thing (I call it Container) with UV unwrapped, painted, with assigned image texture in Nodes. In fact, it was normally displayed until yesterday.
The display method is in Texture. In fact, when I switched to Material, or Solid, the object would still be in wireframe as shown. The whole thing can still be rendered normally.
Hope it's just a wrong button clicked.
Thanks guys, appreciate any help.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Object** tab (with **Sphere** selected) and switch **Maximum Draw Type** to **Textured**.

[image: setup]